# Injecting service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module(app_name).directive('name', ['service', function(service) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      payload: '@trackClicksWithJson'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        //what I had not accounted for in terms of getting service defined here
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

thoughts off-hand in terms of debugging routine? service seems to be functional in other areas of code, had noticed that it had been undefined in click callback

Comment: can you provide some code for the service as well? is it under the same app name? how about a plunker/jsfiddle to help us help you?

Comment: service injected successfully into other areas of code

Comment: what is happening now to make you think the click event cannot see the service?

Comment: @Rhumborl it hadn't been defined when I asked for it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I write

it include the controller, service and the directive.

u can see [demo in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0g0ft44/4/)

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
   
  })
  .service('service', [function() {
    var that = this;
    this.test = function(element) {
      alert("Test Service");     
      
    };
  }])
  .directive('test', ['service', function(service) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
          service.test();
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```css
#test{
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid;
  background:white;
  cursor:pointer;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div id="test" test ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    Click Me
  </div>
</div>
```